# How to fill the form if query returns None

Tags: python, forms, flask, sqlalchemy

I use sqlalchemy to query ip in my database,when result returns ,everything is ok,how can i remain blank in my form when no result returns.

error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Ip'
```

code

```
@main.route('/post', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def post():

    caseid=Masterlist.query.filter_by(Ip=request.args.get('Ip')).first()
    form = RepairForm(request.form)
    print request.form
    if request.form.get("submit"):
        repair = Repair(Ip=form.ip.data,Series=form.series.data,Hostname=form.hostname.data,
                ManagerIp=form.managerip.data,Comp=form.comp.data,Discription=form.discription.data,
                Model=form.model.data,Location=form.location.data,Box=form.box.data,
                Important=form.important.data,Faultype=form.faultype.data,Source=form.source.data,
                Subject=form.subject.data,Body=form.body.data,Classify=form.classify.data,
                Status=form.status.data,auth_id=current_user._get_current_object().id,
                Owner=current_user._get_current_object().username,)
        db.session.add(repair)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('报修成功')
        return redirect(url_for('.index'))
    form.ip.data=caseid.Ip
    form.hostname.data=caseid.Hostname
    form.managerip.data=caseid.Managerip
    form.comp.data=caseid.Comp
    form.model.data=caseid.Model
    form.location.data=caseid.Location
    form.box.data=caseid.Box
    form.classify.data=caseid.Classify
    form.series.data=caseid.Series
    form.discription.data=caseid.Discription

    return render_template('post.html',form=form)
```

Comment: use a `try` block or check `if caseid:` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple if condition for this..

```
@main.route('/post', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def post():

    caseid=Masterlist.query.filter_by(Ip=request.args.get('Ip')).first()
    if caseid:
        form = RepairForm(request.form)
        print request.form
        if request.form.get("submit"):
            repair = Repair(Ip=form.ip.data,Series=form.series.data,Hostname=form.hostname.data,
                ManagerIp=form.managerip.data,Comp=form.comp.data,Discription=form.discription.data,
                Model=form.model.data,Location=form.location.data,Box=form.box.data,
                Important=form.important.data,Faultype=form.faultype.data,Source=form.source.data,
                Subject=form.subject.data,Body=form.body.data,Classify=form.classify.data,
                Status=form.status.data,auth_id=current_user._get_current_object().id,
                Owner=current_user._get_current_object().username,)
            db.session.add(repair)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('报修成功')
            return redirect(url_for('.index'))
        form.ip.data=caseid.Ip
        form.hostname.data=caseid.Hostname
        form.managerip.data=caseid.Managerip
        form.comp.data=caseid.Comp
        form.model.data=caseid.Model
        form.location.data=caseid.Location
        form.box.data=caseid.Box
        form.classify.data=caseid.Classify
        form.series.data=caseid.Series
        form.discription.data=caseid.Discription

        return render_template('post.html',form=form)
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: It shows ValueError: View function did not return a response.I need manual input the form if no result returns.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solution here lol

```
@main.route('/post', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def post():
#   Ip=Ip
#   Ip=Ip
#   print Ip
#   Ip=request.args['Ip']
#   Ip=request.args.get('Ip')

    caseid=Masterlist.query.filter_by(Ip=request.args.get('Ip')).first()
    form = RepairForm(request.form)
    if caseid:

        print request.form
#   print request.form
#   if form.validate_on_submit():
#   if request.method == "POST":
#   if request.form["submit"] == "submitpost":
#   if request.form.get("submit", "submit"):
        if request.form.get("submit"):
            repair = Repair(Ip=form.ip.data,Series=form.series.data,Hostname=form.hostname.data,
                    ManagerIp=form.managerip.data,Comp=form.comp.data,Discription=form.discription.data,
                    Model=form.model.data,Location=form.location.data,Box=form.box.data,
                    Important=form.important.data,Faultype=form.faultype.data,Source=form.source.data,
                    Subject=form.subject.data,Body=form.body.data,Classify=form.classify.data,
                    Status=form.status.data,auth_id=current_user._get_current_object().id,
                    Owner=current_user._get_current_object().username,)
            db.session.add(repair)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('报修成功')
            return redirect(url_for('.index'))
        form.ip.data=caseid.Ip
        form.hostname.data=caseid.Hostname
        form.managerip.data=caseid.Managerip
        form.comp.data=caseid.Comp
        form.model.data=caseid.Model
        form.location.data=caseid.Location
        form.box.data=caseid.Box
        form.classify.data=caseid.Classify
        form.series.data=caseid.Series
        form.discription.data=caseid.Discription

        return render_template('post.html',form=form)
    else:
        if request.form.get("submit"):
            repair = Repair(Ip=form.ip.data,Series=form.series.data,Hostname=form.hostname.data,
                    ManagerIp=form.managerip.data,Comp=form.comp.data,Discription=form.discription.data,
                    Model=form.model.data,Location=form.location.data,Box=form.box.data,
                    Important=form.important.data,Faultype=form.faultype.data,Source=form.source.data,
                    Subject=form.subject.data,Body=form.body.data,Classify=form.classify.data,
                    Status=form.status.data,auth_id=current_user._get_current_object().id,
                    Owner=current_user._get_current_object().username,)
            db.session.add(repair)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('报修成功')
            return redirect(url_for('.index'))
        return render_template('postmanual.html')
```